# How to find all paths with n-distance from a node in a graph with cycles?

Tags: graphs, asymptotics, search-algorithms

I have to find all the paths that have some n-distance from a start node. The destination node is not given. It seems that this problem is very hard to solve because in this scenario I am working with a geographical map, thus there exist cycles as well. Finding all of these paths must take a large amount of time because there exist so many possible paths. Let's take this example:

I have given some node on my map and have to find all paths that are 5km from that node. This would result in many paths with the same edges. Also there are extremely many different paths to calculate, so it would not be possible to calculate this in a reasonable amount of time.

Does anyone have some suggestion to this? I have considered modifications of BFS or DFS, but these, at least what I understand would take O(n!) because they have to find each path that possibly exists.

Comment: Shortest path with memoization (dynamic programming) should help quite a bit.

Comment: What do you mean by a path that has some n-distance?  Do you mean a path of length n?  Do the edges in your graph have weights or not?  Why is this hard?  it seems straightforward to enumerate all such paths, in time linear in the number of such paths.  Yes, in some graphs it will take a very long time because there may be exponentially many paths, but that's a consequence of the problem statement and not something that any algorithm can ever eliminate.  I'm not sure what kind of answer you are expecting...

Comment: I mean a path of length n. Finding every path of length n from a given node. The edges have weights. The issue is that I have such a large graph that it would take a long time. What I am asking is, whether or not there is a method that is able to do this in polynomial time.